# Повторное использование scanf

Tags: c

Мне нужно сделать консольное меню с защитой от неверно выбранного символа, я пытаюсь сделать так:

```
int a;
loop:
printf("1 - .., 2 - ..\n");
scanf("%d",&a);
if (a != 1 && a != 2){
printf("Неверный выбор");
goto loop;
}
```

В итоге запускается бесконечный цикл без возможности повторно ввести число а, в чем может быть проблема? Спасибо!

Comment: scanf возвращает число, которое показывает, сколько переменных удалось прочитать переменных. Но если хочется сделать совсем красиво, то нужно getline+sscanf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
int way = 0;

for (; way < 1 || way > 2; puts("Неверный выбор, попробуйте снова")) {
  puts("1 - ...");
  puts("2 - ...");

  switch (scanf("%d", &way)) {
    case -1: // EOF
      puts("Ooops.. EOF found.");
      exit(1);

    case 0: // мусор
      scanf("%*s");
      continue;
  }
}
```

Кстати, если из этого сделать функцию, то получится покрасивее.

Comment: Да, так отлично работает, спасибо!

Comment: @GlebKamisaraw, немного обновил.

Comment: А можно подробней узнать, что происходит, когда scanf возвращает 0, мне не очень понятен смысл scanf("%*s") этой строчки

Comment: @GlebKamisaraw, `%s` - прочитать строку (до пробельного символа), а `*` перед форматом - "никуда не сохраняя". Можно ещё `%*[^\r\n]`, чтобы пропускать до конца строки, а не до порбела.